# Which component required to build UI react-native

Tags: react-native, styles

I wanted to build `UI` as displayed in the below images, Can anyone suggest me which about component needed to used for making this UI in react-native

[this for height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH13X.jpg)

[this for gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bciP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use picker for `height`**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker#__docusaurus from the core is deprecated.

Separate module

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-picker

**Use this for `gender`.**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/segmentedcontrolios#__docusaurus from the core is deprecated.

Separate module

https://github.com/react-native-community/segmented-control

Edit: for gender do this

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
  this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
    { YourData.map(item=>
     <Picker.Item label={item.label} value={item.value} />
      )
    }
  </Picker>
```

Comment: can i put Icon in the gender? , and i need to do loop in the height  to have all the number i need or what i need to do

Comment: Yes, you can put icon in gender, Also I have updated my answer about height.

Comment: Thank you for help, contact with you, if i have question about react-native, somewhere?